# Use same dependencies for 2 different library modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have library module A that is used in a couple of app modules and a library module B that also gets used in a couple of other modules.

Both already each use `api` instead of `implementation` in their dependencies so the app modules don't need to declare the dependencies again. But they each define their own dependencies which overlap.

How can I get both library modules to share the same dependencies without declaring them twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be optimal but what I did in the end (because it kind of worked in MY USE CASE):

Make one of the libraries depend on the other and then put all overlapping libraries on the one that is depended on using

```
api project("moduleName")
```

Also make sure you use api instead of implementation on the individual libraries to inherit them to sub modules